# Ejecutar RestTemplate con un recurso externos sobre HTTPS

Tags: java, spring-boot, certificado-ssl

Estoy intentando consumir un endpoint publico que esta disponible tanto en http como en SSL, `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1` el cual devuelve un json muy simple.

He configurado mi RestTemplate asi:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    @Value("${https.remote.proxy.host}")
    private String PROXY_URI;

    @Value("${https.remote.proxy.port}")
    private int PROXY_PORT;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {

        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,
        new InetSocketAddress(PROXY_URI, PROXY_PORT));
        requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);

        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }
}
```

Ademas hice lo siguiente, fui a `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1` en chrome para descargar el certificado, haciendo clic en el simbolo del candado ⟼ valid ⟼ Detailles ⟼ Copiar a archivo como jsonplaceholder.cer y con el KeyStore Explorer copié este certificado en los cacerts de JAVA (JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security).

Cuando hago lo siguiente:

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

@RequestMapping(value="test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Post getPost() {
    Post post = restTemplate.getForObject("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", Post.class);
    return post;
}
```

Obtengo una respuesta exitosa :

```
{
    "userId": "1",
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

Pero cuando hago lo mismo sobre `https` obtengo el siguiente error:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1520596009201,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException",
    "message": "I/O error on GET request for \"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1\": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target",
    "path": "/api/v1/sepa/test/"
}
```

Que proviene desde Java:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
```

Qué estoy olvidando? Esta prueba la hago con la intencion de probar el RestTemplate poraue mas adelante tendré que conectarme a una API de un proveedor.

Comment: Con el keyStore Explorer no sé que puede haber fallado, pero puedes probar con `keytool -import -trustcacerts -file /path/a/fichero.cer -alias MiAlias -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit` (sacado de [aqui](https://myshittycode.com/2015/12/17/java-https-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-2/))

Comment: Gracias, también lo he intentado directamente desde consola, pero el resultado es el mismo; no sé qué puedo estar olvidando, talvez alguna configuracion en el @Bean de RestTemplate,

Comment: Has comprobado que no tengas dos versiones de Java instaladas? JDK y JRE...

Comment: Si, he comprobado también eso, corri la aplicacion en un ordenador fuera de la red y del proxy para validar y funciono, incluso sin agregar los certificados al cacerts, ahora estoy incluso mas confundido.